# Made an error in the graduate application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

After submitting the application I found my undergraduate education was mistakenly classified as a graduate degree. All my other transcript and CV say the correct things. What can I do besides contacting the admission office? The admission office is non-responding.

Comment: Contacting the admissions office sounds like the most useful course of action - why do you need an alternative?

Comment: @RuaraidhDobson Maybe they mean *in addition* to contacting the admission office? Probably asking in case there are other obvious ways to address the error (and which OP might be blamed for not trying). I agree that contacting the admissions office is sufficient for a minor error like this. To the committee, OP might appear slightly careless, but not dishonest.

Comment: @richard Exactly! Since the admission office is too busy they just ignored my email...